# Is $\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)$ an invertible $R[x]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)$ be an $\mathbb R[x]$-module. I wish to find whether it is invertible or not?

*Invertible* means there should be some $\mathbb R[x]$-module $M$ such that:

$$\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)\otimes_{\mathbb R[x]} M\cong \mathbb R[x].$$

I also read that if we can show it is principal then it is automatically invertible but I am so confused.

Firstly I cannot correctly calculate $\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)$ and cannot figure out the inverted module.

Comment: This can't be invertible because it has torsion. Think about what acting by $x^5-7$ on both sides of your isomorphism will do.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "acting by $x^5-7$"

Comment: Given an element $m$ of your module, you can get an element $(x^5-7)m$ by acting by $x^5-7$.

Comment: Modules are cyclic, not principal. Ideals are principal.