# Invertible Modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules

I have the task to show that the module $R[X]/(x^5-7)$ is not invertible. Actually decide wether it is or not, but I am pretty sure it is not invertible. So my first attempt was to say the following:

We have an Isomorphism $f:R[X]\rightarrow R[X]/(x^5-7)\otimes_{R[X]} R'$ for an $R[X]$-module $R'$. My idea was to define a map from R[X] to R[X] that is injective, and that sends X to something in the ideal $(X^5-7)$. Maybe i a able to conclue that the induced map $R[X]/(x^5-7)\otimes_{R[X]} R'\rightarrow R[X]/(x^5-7)\otimes_{R[X]} R'$ is not injective, while the upper one is which is a contradiction. But I don't really know how. Every answer is apprechiated!

Comment: Asked previously on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370146/is-mathbb-rx-x5-7-an-invertible-rx-module).

Comment: oh true, thank you:)

Comment: Honestly i do not get you answer there. Could you elaborate what acting by $x^5-7$ means?

Comment: Ohh does it just mean multiplication? That makes a lot of sense actually. I will try to answer my Question myself, maybe you can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. And as I explain in the comments there, the action of $R$ on an $R$-module $M$ is the map $R\times M\to M$ which sends $(r,m)\mapsto rm$. (So yes, multiplication is probably a synonym.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after the hint of KReiser in the other post, i think i got a solution. Let $f:R[X]\rightarrow R[X]/(x^5-7)\otimes_{R[X]} R'$ be the isomorphism in the question. We have the following equation: $$f(x^5-7)=(x^5-7)f(1)=(x^5-7)\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\otimes b_i=\sum_{i=0}^n ((x^5-7)a_i)\otimes b_i=0$$

Probably there is a certain form for the image of 1 here but i dont know it and it does not matter either. If we take the preimage we get $f^{-1}(0)=0=x^5-7$ which shows that f is not injective, thus not an isomorphism.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track but could be a little clearer. For instance, defining $f$ in your answer would probably be helpful (even just to save scrolling up to the question) and then making it clear that you're showing that $f$ can't be an isomorphism because it's not injective would make the answer a little more understandable.

Comment: Sure! I will edit that. Thanks for the advice